# Why is a function without attribute is being called in ASP.NET MVC even though the request is a post request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm following this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

It describes a situation when a user click a button and then a function without an attribute is called.

But when a function with HttpPost attribute is added, this function is called and not the function without the attribute.

The button initiates Html.BeginForm() which creates a post request. So why did the function without the attribute got called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A submit button will **ALWAYS** initiate a `HttpPost` request.

A hyperlink on the other hand (`a` tag), that points to an action will **ALWAYS** be a `HttpGet`.

**EDIT: I realise your confusion, see below to demonstrate what @RickAndMSFT is trying to say:**

Given that we have the following action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchIndex()
{
}
```

**This action will ONLY accept `HttpGet` requests**

**NOTE:** If we take away the `HttpGet` attribute, it will accept **ALL Request Types**.

Therefore, if you have:

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex()
{
}
```

**There is no need for a post method because the method above already accepts post requests.** This is the case because the page in question isn't actually modifying/saving/creating anything, it's just listing data.

Comment: In the sample BeginForm instructs the routing system to use the GET method.

Comment: But the first BeginForm there is just: 
`@using (Html.BeginForm()){   
         <p> Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />  
         <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p>`
        }

Comment: Right-- Perhaps I need to point out what @mattytommo stated - submit always makes a POST request. Can you mark mattytommo and my answers as useful?

Comment: I can't because I don't have enough reputation.
I still don't understand why the HttpGet function was called when the edit button was pressed, which initiated a BeginForm and that should have sent a post request.

Comment: @RonenFestinger I think I see your confusion, although in his blog Rick states that `SearchIndex` is a GET action method, *it's not strictly true*. The actual `SearchIndex` `ActionResult` isn't decorated with the `HttpGet` attribute **which means that it will also accept `HttpPost` requests. An `ActionResult` controller method is **only restricted to either post or get requests if you explicitly specify it as an attribute (i.e. HttpGet)

Comment: @RonenFestinger Updated my answer to try and make it clearer :)

Comment: @RickAndMSFT I've upvoted your answer, if I could, I'd upvote you again for the blog post :)

Comment: @mattytommo "A submit button will ALWAYS initiate a HttpPost request." - wrong. What about `<form method="get"...`?

Comment: @mattytommo Thanks, that clears things. So now I understand that if no attribute applied, the function will accept both post and get. Before that, I thought the default is get and that's what the function accepts. So the BeginForm() sent a post request which was handled by this dual purpose function, and when we added another function with an HttpPost attribute and same name the request got routed to this function. It leads me to think that defining a function without any attribute is not a good idea, why would you want a function which will handle both get and post?

Answer (score 4):

thanks for reading my Tutorial. You might want to read the [MVC 4 version](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4). As @mattytommo writes, the submit causes a POST. Later in the tutorial you use the BeginForm overload to route to submit to a GET method.
The ASP.NET MVC pattern uses the same method name with POST or GET. Get requests go to the HTTPGET method (the default, doesn't require an the [HttpGet] attribute) and submits go to the [HttpPost] method. Take a look at all the edit/create methods - usually the same method name. Since you can't overload C# on attributes, when the parameters are the same, we use another attribute to change the method name (see the end of the tutorial).